# Program to calculate standard deviation gives incorrect values

Tags: fortran, gfortran, fortran90

I'm attempting to write a program that reads data from 2 different files and calculates the mean, standard deviation and standard error for both separately. Each files contains 12 values (monthly rainfall), here's the values:

5.0, 
6.6,
9.3,
10.4,
14.0,
18.0,
16.9,
18.6,
15.4,
13.1,
5.4,
7.6,

and

3.2,
4.3,
9.5,
13.0,
14.5,
19.2,
20.8,
19.0,
17.2,
12.9,
7.2,
2.0.

Here's my code:

```
program data
implicit none

integer             :: R, F
double precision    :: x, sum = 0, mean, y, mean2, sum2 = 0, var =0, sdv, 
var2 = 0, sdv2


open(unit = 100, file = 'tmax_1910.txt', status = 'old', action = 'read')
 do R = 1,  12
 read(100,*) x
 sum = sum + x

end do

mean = (sum)/12

 do R = 1, 12
  var = var + (((x - mean)**2.0)/12)
  sdv = var**0.5

end do
open(unit = 200, file = 'tmax_2010.txt', status = 'old', action = 'read')
 do F = 1, 12
 read(200,*) y
 sum2 = sum2 + y

end do

mean2 = (sum2)/12

 do F = 1, 12
  var2 = var2 + (((y - mean2)**2.0)/12)
  sdv2 = var2**0.5
end do

print *, 'mean=', mean, 'mean2=', mean2, 'sdv=', sdv, 'sdv2=', sdv2

end program data
```

Comparing what I get to an online calculator, I get the correct values for mean (11.69 and 11.89 respectively), but my values for standard deviation are off. The first value I get is 4.09..., the second is 9.9... whilst the first is meant to be 4.9..., and the second 6.6...

I can't see any error with my variance formula, so what is causing this?

Thanks.

Comment: your program uses the last read values of x and y i.e: x=7.6 and y = 2. to calculate sdv and sdv2 . you should use arrays.